# use VALUE AS cell color

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, colors

Okay I researched this as much as possible before I posted so I hope this is not a repost but here goes...

I made a datatable, lets say it has a coulmn called "cartype" , then I added a column called "color"

well, I bound a gridview what I want to do is use a label, and have its FORECOLOR be the VALUE in the column "color".

I tried this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="cartype" HeaderText="Cars"  ItemStyle-Width="130" ItemStyle-ForeColor='<% Eval("Color") %>' />
```

but I got an error about

"Cannot create an object of type System.drawing.color from its string representation '<%Eval("color")%>' for the 'ForeColor' Property.

I also tried adding a template field and got the same result.

I was trying not to use the rowdatabound event and use .Cells[3] , because then when I add columns, it's going to change the cell number, and switch up everything! I was hoping I could make it cleaner by binding the color with the data.

Comment: What was the markup you used for the template field?

Comment: The reason for the error is that the runtime expects the value of ForeColor to be a color, NOT a string. The runtime cannot create "Red" from the string "Red". 

Why are you trying to do this with a code block anyway? use ondatabinding and set the color based on a condition at codebehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I ended up doing this. sad :(

At the VERY END of my grid I added an ASP:Hidden template field

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hColor" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Color") %>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the RowDataBoundEvent I did this

```
Dim hid As HiddenField
hid = e.Row.FindControl("hColor")
If (hid.Value <> Nothing) Then
   e.Row.Cells(1).ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + hid.Value)
End If
```

PS. I heart C#. Dont like VB.NET. lol :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
 ForeColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("Color")) %>'
```

?

Comment: Good suggestion, but this throws 
"Databdinging expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event.  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Boundfield does not have a Databinding event"

Comment: If you got this error with mine, then I wonder why you didn't get it with the answer from @wcraft?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the runtime expects the value of ForeColor to be a color, NOT a string. The runtime cannot create "Red" from the string "Red".

You can create a function at code behind using following example to work around your issue .. function will accept string color value and will return System color. Also before populating gridview you can store the color column in the arraylist and use that arraylist to return system color. Not the best way but cant think of anything else.

```
 ForeColor='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Color")) == "Blue" ? System.Drawing.Blue>
```

Comment: Dang, at that point it might be easier just to make a new column at the end, item template of Hidden Field. then do a 

e.row.cells[0].Forecolor = "#" + e.row.cells[10].text